# Binding templated item to Converter's Value property in DataTemplate

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm, silverlight-4.0, datatemplate

I'm using Silverlight 4.

I have a DataTemplate defined for a DataGrid which allows me to successfully display values to my liking. I have a Rating control inside of this DataTemplate that has a Converter on the Value property like so..

```
<DataTemplate>
    <toolkit:Rating Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}" ItemCount="5" />
</DataTemplate>
```

When I step through the code and get into the converter, I see that the value parameter isn't the item corresponding to the row being rendered by the template but my ViewModel that is the DataContext of the DataGrid itself!

Now, if I adjust this slightly like so,

```
<DataTemplate>
    <toolkit:Rating Value="{Binding SomeProperty Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}" ItemCount="5" />
</DataTemplate>
```

The value passed to MyConverter is SomeProperty of the item rendered by the DataTemplate.

Does anyone know why this might be? How can I bind to the item the template refers to instead of the DataContext of the DataGrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

During the MeasureOverride stage of Silverlight's DataGrid, my converter is being invoked. It feels like a bug in the DataGrid's implementation of MeasureOverride to ignore the

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}"></DataGrid>
```

binding expression with respect to a defined DataTemplate at this stage and use the DataContext of the DataGrid which will certainly cause a typical Converter to fail.

My band-aid solution for now is to add an if statement in my converter implementation to just make sure the type of value I get is what I expect so it passes MeasureOverride.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is ExpectedType)
        //do things
    else
       //return an instance of targetType
}
```

Can anyone confirm if this still happens in SL5?

Comment: Are you not using that template in a DataGridTemplateColumn?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez Good point. My DataTemplate actually exists inside of a DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate to describe the template of my DataGrid's RowDetails content.

Answer (score 0):

Try `"{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}"`

Comment: This was a good idea. I tried it and see the same behavior. This source shows the period syntax and omitting the path to be identical. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx